# shapely 2.0 warning Convert the '.coords' to a NumPy array instead related to appending pandas with dictionary

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

In my code I append a single row to a geopandas dataframe as a dictionary. Although the code works, it prints this warning message below related to the future shapely 2.0 upgrade (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migration.html) .

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py:118: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: The array interface is deprecated and will no longer work in Shapely 2.0. Convert the '.coords' to a numpy array instead.
  arr = construct_1d_object_array_from_listlike(values)
```

The code is the one below:

```
gp_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns =['id', 'geometry'], crs=crs)
new_row = {'id': 0, 'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f5c56072bd0>}
gp_df = gp_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True) # here is the line that triggers the warning
gp_df.to_file(filename, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Unless I am missing something, the warning seems completely unrelated to the code. Does anybody know if this will become an issue when Shapely 2.0 is finally implemented and, if so, how to fix it?

Answer (score 8):

I think you should be fine, based on what is documented in https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migration.html#creating-numpy-arrays-of-geometry-objects:

> However, starting with Shapely 1.8, the above code will show deprecation warnings that cannot be avoided (depending on the geometry type, NumPy tries to access the array interface of the objects or check if an object is iterable or has a length, and those operations are all deprecated now. The end result is still correct, but the warnings appear nonetheless). Specifically in this case, it is fine to ignore those warnings (and the only way to make them go away):

> ```
> import warnings
> from shapely.errors import ShapelyDeprecationWarning
>
> geoms = [Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(2, 2)]
> arr = np.empty(len(geoms), dtype="object")
>
> with warnings.catch_warnings():
>     warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ShapelyDeprecationWarning)
>     arr[:] = geoms
> ```

> **In Shapely 2.0, the geometry objects will no longer be sequence like and those deprecation warnings will be removed** (and thus the filterwarnings will no longer be necessary), and creation of NumPy arrays will generally be more robust.